# Grouping rails records by week and adding them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

I'm using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1 and Postgresql

I have a records table with a day column (datetime), and a value column (decimal). I want to add all the value columns that are in the same week accounting for the time zone of the user available here: current_user.time_zone

The records could be in the 1000s so speed is important.

I used the groupdate gem like this:

```
Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).count
```

But it returned a hash of 4 datetimes, and there are 9 records in total.

**Solution from BroiSatse:**

Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).sum(:value)

**However when :value is json This is the error I get:**

```
SELECT SUM(value->'430') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(json) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(value->'430') AS sum_total_nutriti...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM(value->'430') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(json) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(value->'430') AS sum_total_nutriti...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM(value->'430') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

Comment: Try `Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).sum(:value)`

Comment: Thank you! One issue though. When :value is json I have to do this Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).sum(:value['430'].to_f) and it prints 0 for all the sums

Comment: Well, I'm quite surprised you didn't get any other error here. :) Value is a symbol, when you execute `[]` method with a string, it will convert symbol to string and return the position the passed string starts within your symbol. In this case that's gona be `nil`. `nil.to_f` is `0.0`. So you're calling `sum(0.0)` which executes the query `SELECT SUM(0.0) ...` - obviously it is zero.

I haven't work with json columns in postgres yet and I don't think ActiveRecord has built in support for them. You can try `sum("value->'430'")`, no idea if it will work though.

Comment: I pasted the error I got in. Thanks for the help